# Getting a PDF from WCF to WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, pdf, stream

Okay, here's what I have...

On one server, a WCF hosted in IIS. This one handles a bunch of stuff for an ASP.NET application which resides on the same server (mostly db calls). In the ASP app, there's an embedded iFrame which contains a PDF document viewer.

On another server, a WCF hosted in a Windows service. This one handles calls from the first WCF and kicks off a third-party document program which generates PDF files. For now, I have a dummy PDF file sitting on the C:\ drive to play with.

My mission: To *somehow* have a function in WCF #2 return a copy of the PDF document to WCF #1, which will save it to the local ASP application directory, so the embedded viewer can display it to a user.

So far I've tried having WCF #2 return a FileStream object but no luck there. I guess that's a big no-no in the WCF world (I'm a noob).

I have no idea how to accomplish this, most of my efforts are proving futile. How would YOU handle this? Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have WCF2 take the PDF and return it as a byte array:

```
   // fs is your FileStream
   byte[] Data = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Read(Data,0,fs.Length);
```

WCF1 calls WCF2 and reads the byte array, then saves it to disk

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
bw.Write(buff);
bw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jason -- I did something similar. Thought I'd post for the next guy:

WCF #2:

```
Public Function GetPDF_Byte() As Byte() Implements IService1.GetPDF_Byte
    Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\211LD.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim ImageData As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}

    fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))

    fs.Close()

    GetPDF_Byte = ImageData
End Function
```

And, WCF #1 which calls #2 and writes the file to disk:

```
Sub Main
    Dim WCF As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client
    Dim ByteData As Byte()
    Dim oFileStream As System.IO.FileStream

    ByteData = WCF.GetPDF_Byte
    oFileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("C:\NewPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create)
    oFileStream.Write(ByteData, 0, ByteData.Length)
    oFileStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Hope that can help someone else!